# Sometimes "The specified feature has been temporarily disabled for this application"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

it sometimes returned :

{"error_code"=>"2000", "error_message"=>"The specified feature has been temporarily disabled for this application", "state"=>"d022a262e11b1a8bebe4bccb86319514e870fb6657b6aee8"}

from facebook when using facebook login

apache_log:

```
85.135.128.63 - - [08/May/2013:19:07:40 +0200] "GET /users/auth/facebook HTTP/1.1" 302 250 "http://www.itolar.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31"
85.135.128.63 - - [08/May/2013:19:07:41 +0200] "GET /users/auth/facebook/callback?error_code=2000&error_message=The+specified+feature+has+been+temporarily+disabled+for+this+application&state=d022a262e11b1a8bebe4bccb86319514e870fb6657b6aee8 HTTP/1.1" 500 728 "http://www.itolar.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31"
```

But when i tried two different accounts to do same thing, everything works fine
I am using omniauth-facebook on Ruby on Rails

Do anybody know whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be hitting a rate limit.  Try making less frequent calls and/or optimizing them (ie via batch calls).  Also check App Insights -> Activity & Errors.